# Where, Group by and Sum specific column in LINQ

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this SQL query that gives the result I want. Please help me convert this to LINQ.

```
SELECT skill, sum (skillLevel) 
FROM ReportView
WHERE jobTitle = 'Graphic Designer'
GROUP BY skill
```

The query gives the result as below.

```
  skill      (No column Name)
-------------------------------
Photoshop         10
Illustrator        8
```

I have tried this but I get anonymous type errors.

```
    var results = db.ReportViews
       .Where(x => x.jobTitle == "Graphic Designer")
       .GroupBy(x => x.skill)
       .Select(y =>
       new
       {
           skill = y.Select(x => x.skill),
           skillLevel = y.Sum(s => s.skillLevel)
       }).ToList();
```

Comment: `sum(skillLevel) AS SkillLevel`

Comment: You are almost there. Just replace `y.Select(x => x.skill)` with `y.Key`.